# How should a scorm 1.2 package be rendered in browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, scorm, scorm1.2

What would be a good way to render/deliver a SCORM package in the browser?

Details:
This is my first encounter with SCORM. I have read a lot about this in the last days and what it seems hard to understand is how to launch the package after it is unzipped and how should the communication with the backend should be established.

We have SCORM 1.2 packages with assesmets and navigation embedded (these are not created by me)

> "The three components of the SCORM Run-Time Environment are defined in
>   this document as **Launch**, Application Program Interface (API) and
>   Data Model. The details of these elements of the SCORM Run-time
>   Environment are described in Book 3."  source ADL SCORM 1.2 Overview
>   Documentation

I was referring to the Launch part of RTE. After unzipping the package there is a main html file but it is not opening correctly.

**Update after comments:**

I'm a junior ruby on rails developer and I don't seem to understant what would be the right way to implement a scorm compliant lms with or without ruby on rails. We have a LMS and now we want to add Scorm also.

- I am getting SCORM 1.2 packages built with easygenerator that have assessments and navigation

TODO:
I have to be able to run these packages and get the status (passed, failed) and the results

The problem is that I have read most of the things I found online but it is still not clear how I should be able to do this.

So far I found a scorm player [here](http://scormpool.com/search/player.aspx) and I am using it to be able to start the courses, and now I have to get the results and the status

Any advice is appreciated, thanks a million :), I'm so passed deadline

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. A SCORM package is a way of packaging up web content into a zip package. So you would unzip the package and then open the launch page in a browser. What have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: the scorm packages that I got are made with easy generator and have a main html but when I am loading it it gives an error: Connect with LMS disappeared. Restart the course

Comment: Depending on how its programmed to work the SCO will begin searching for the Runtime API provided by the LMS.  If one isn't present then it may allow it to run locally or failover to something else.  Are you importing these into a LMS or just launching them local?